# CLion: run tests before build

Tags: cmake, automated-tests, googletest, clion, jetbrains-ide

I made a project in CLion (C++ + CMake) where I have a *shared library* project with 2 configurations **Debug | Release**. I have also implemented google tests for unit testing.

When the configuration is **Release** I would like to run some tests (or all) before the build. When the tests fail the library should **not** be build.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: You have to *build* the library first before executing tests on it. Unless, you are running tests on other libraries in your project, which you have not mentioned in your question. Please provide a [Minimal Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your CMake project to show how it is configured now, and compare it to the desired behavior.

Comment: I should have said that I want to run only _unit_ tests and not _business logic_ tests. For the unit tests the library doesn't have to be build. I have found the answer though. I will update the question and post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer with `add_custom_command()`.
In my main *CMakeLists.txt* I have

```
if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Release")
   #Rebuild the tests just in case some tests has changed and the executable was not rebuild
   add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" --target tests --
           )

   if(${WIN32})
      set(TESTS_BIN tests.exe)
   else()
      set(TESTS_BIN tests)
   endif()
   #Run the tests executable
   add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
           COMMAND "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${TESTS_BIN}"
           )
endif()
```

The `add_custom_command()` is smart therefore when the *tests* executable doesn't return 0 (all test have passed successfully) the build will fail and the library will not be build.